# How to decode this byte code to float values using python

Tags: python, decoding

I've received byte code similar to this:

`}Pl\xA1u#\x1EW\x02\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x85\xA9\xF4>\x08\x00\x00\x00\xBF\xE8\xA3B\xC30\xECA\xFA~`

How can this be decoded to normal value?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

`data.decode("utf-16")`, where data is your byte code.

Answer (score 0):

If the bytes are binary format of float sequence, you need to know the byte order when serializing them first.

And in Python, we could use **struct.unpack()** with format **f** to unpack the bytes to float.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html for reference.